# How do I remove unwanted space from a PDF that was generated using HTML?

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I am using [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/) to create a PDF. The structure of my HTML template is quite basic, using tables (and nested tables).

I am able to create a PDF, and most of the PDF renders correctly. However there is a lot of unwanted space above/below the nested tables. This needs removing as I need all of the information to fit on one page (see below).

[image: Evidence of unwanted space]

You can view the HTML for the template [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwoughe2/). From this you should see that the actual HTML renders with minimal amounts of white space.

I know I am calling the HTML2PDF class correctly, but just for reference, here is how I'm calling it:

```
require(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html = file_get_contents("pdf_template.tpl");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output($path . $file_name, 'F');
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Setting `margin`, `padding`, `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to 0 on all `<table>`, `<td>` and `<tr>` tags.
- Removing any indentations between the `<td>` and `<tr>` tags, as other SO spacing issues seem to be resolved by this.

How do I remove this rendered space from the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a lot of white space between and around your elements. This may be causing the html to render wrong - a new line in html won't render anything, but it might be rendered as a new line in the pdf.

Remove all the white space from around the html elements:

e.g.

```
    <td class="main-td">    <span>Your Reference</span>

    </td>

    <td ...
```

into

```
<td class="main-td"><span>Your Reference</span></td>
<td ...
```

(not the lack of leading white space)